# Turtle graphics: keyboard bound function not working after first time

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am an inexperienced Python 3 programmer. I created this game following a tutorial on YouTube using the turtle module and I came across a problem. Here is a portion of the code where I think the problem is:

```
def missile_status(self):
    i = 0
    if self.status == "firing":
        while i <= 5:
            i += 1
            turtle.time.sleep(1)
    if i >= 5:
        self.status = "ready"

def shoot(self):
    if self.status == "ready":
        self.goto(player_traits.xcor(), player_traits.ycor())
        self.setheading(player_traits.heading())
        self.status = "firing"
        self.st()
```

I bound the function `shoot` to the space bar. When I press the space bar the first time, it executes the function and works fine. But afterwards, if I press the space bar to shoot again (after five seconds) the function doesn't work (it doesn't shoot).

Comment: You could show how to link the spacebar with the function.

Comment: I used turtle.onkey

Answer (score 0):

You've probably not supplied enough code to debug but any tutorial that includes a `time.sleep()` in an event-driven environment like turtle is suspect.  Below is a complete, runnable, simplified example of how I might approach this problem.  The player only moves in one dimension, to keep the example simple, but the basic idea should also work in two dimensions:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from functools import partial

class Missle(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("circle")

        self.hideturtle()
        self.shapesize(0.5)
        self.setheading(90)
        self.penup()

        screen.onkey(self.shoot, "space")  # enable shooting

    def track_missle(self, milliseconds=5000):
        if milliseconds > 0:
            self.forward(10)
            milliseconds -= 100

            # can't use partial() due to object has no attribute '__name__'
            screen.ontimer(lambda: self.track_missle(milliseconds), 100)
        else:
            self.hideturtle()  # this shot is finished
            screen.onkey(self.shoot, "space")  # reenable shooting

    def shoot(self):
        screen.onkey(None, "space")  # disable further shots for now

        self.goto(player.position())  # shots originate from player's position
        self.showturtle()

        screen.ontimer(self.track_missle, 100)  # move for 5 secs, update every 0.1 sec

class Player(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("triangle")

        self.settiltangle(90)  # move side to side but face upward
        self.penup()
        self.sety(-screen.window_height() / 4)

        screen.onkey(partial(self.forward, 10), "Right")
        screen.onkey(partial(self.backward, 10), "Left")

screen = Screen()
player = Player()
missle = Missle()

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```